# Spring Data Cassandra cant find entity class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I'm trying to persist a cassandra entity but on startup I get: 
`Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.service.model.Cart!`

This is my entity class:

```
package com.service.model;

import io.vavr.collection.LinkedHashMap;
import io.vavr.collection.Map;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKey;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.function.Function;

@ToString
@Table("carts")
public class Cart {

  @Getter
  @PrimaryKey
  private final UUID uuid;
  private final Map<CartItemKey, CartItem> items;

  public Cart(UUID uuid) {
    this(uuid, LinkedHashMap.empty());
  }

  private Cart(UUID uuid, Map<CartItemKey, CartItem> items) {
    this.uuid = Objects.requireNonNull(uuid, "Cart's uuid cannot be null");
    this.items = Objects.requireNonNull(items, "Cart's items cannot be null");
  }
}
```

This is my CassandraConfig:

```
package com.service.configuration;

import com.service.model.Cart;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.AbstractClusterConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.CassandraCustomConversions;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.keyspace.CreateKeyspaceSpecification;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.keyspace.KeyspaceOption;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static java.util.Collections.singletonList;

@Configuration
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractClusterConfiguration {

  @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name}")
  private String keyspaceName;
  @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contact-points}")
  private String contactPoints;

  @Override
  protected List<CreateKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceCreations() {
    return singletonList(
        CreateKeyspaceSpecification.createKeyspace(keyspaceName)
        .ifNotExists()
        .with(KeyspaceOption.DURABLE_WRITES, true)
        .withSimpleReplication());
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean getMetricsEnabled() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  protected String getContactPoints() {
    return contactPoints;
  }

  @Bean
  public CassandraCustomConversions customConversions() {
    List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
    converters.add(new CartWriteConverter());
    converters.add(new CartReadConverter());
    return new CassandraCustomConversions(converters);
  }

  static class CartWriteConverter implements Converter<Cart, String> {
    public String convert(Cart source) {
      try {
        return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(source);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
      }
    }
  }

  static class CartReadConverter implements Converter<String, Cart> {
    public Cart convert(String source) {
      if (StringUtils.hasText(source)) {
        try {
          return new ObjectMapper().readValue(source, Cart.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

And lastly my Application:

```
package com.service.cart;

import org.axonframework.springboot.autoconfig.AxonServerAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableCassandraRepositories;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;

@EnableCaching
@EnableAsync
@EnableFeignClients
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
    AxonServerAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "com.service.repository")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

What seems puzzling to me is that when I remove `customConversions()` bean it fails with a different error - not being able to map vavr Map, so spring must have scanned and registered this entity so that it got inspected. This is expected while it is not cassandra data type but in my understanding adding my custom conversions should solve this problem.

I also tried experimenting with `@EntityScan` with the same results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your Entity isn't annotated with @Entity or any other annotation that makes it visible in the entire scope of your project. Could that be the cause?

Comment: @EarthMind perhaps, I will try it but according to official documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#cassandra.getting-started Person class isnt annotated with Entity either.
EDIT: Same error. I think its CassandraMappingContext thats not getting properly set up but all tutorials dont touch on this subject.

Comment: How is `Cart` supposed to map to a Cassandra `Row`?  Converters consider `Cart` as a simple type and `Cart` would be converted to a JSON string.

Comment: @mp911de I thought that it would be mapped 1:1 using provided Converters. I cant provide a reference right now in the plethora of sites I visited but I read somewhere that Cassandra Row could be considered a simple String and a Converter is there to give you fine grained control over conversion.

Comment: You should be good by removing both converters – you cannot apply converters on a top-level type. A converter caused to ignore all metadata on the class and puts the mapping in your hands. I think you rather need to provide converters for `CartItemKey` and  `CartItem` since they need a proper mapping to a `map`-typed Cassandra column.

Comment: @mp911de should CartItemKey and CartItem be then declared as UserDefinedType in DataType.Name.Map - @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.MAP, typeArguments = {DataType.Name.UDT, DataType.Name.UDT})

Comment: If they are UDT's then simply add `@UserDefinedType`

Comment: Hi @SokPomaranczowy
Were you able to solve this error? I am getting the same error though I ain't using any complex types.